# Unsupported symbols appearing in lieu of white space

Tags: html, css, browser

[image: Unsupported symbols appearing]

This bug was captured on a Windows machine with Chrome (on my Windows instead of a box it's an "L". I don't understand why these symbols are appearing.

This is my html code:

```
<p> ... are linked  to specific <strong>disease</strong> or physical <strong>traits</strong>.  Other sections of DNA ... </p>
```

Is this a browser specific issue/user specific issue? Or is this a issue with my code (like adding another fallback font)?

Any ideas, suggestions, direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have character set specified? (<meta charset="UTF-8"> in the beginning of the head section) Is your html document in the same character set in your editor? If you are using database, are your database connection and fields in the same character set?

Comment: I have the meta tag in my head. How do I check if the html doc is the same char set as my editor? I'm using Atom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at it it seems like you might be using non-breaking spaces. It is unusual that that is a problem for a font, but you might want to just not use them. Most Editors can highlight such "invisible characters" in one way or another. It is worth searching for that for your editor.

Comment: Some of the unsupported symbols came from double spaces in my <p> tags. So fixed those.

However there are still more unsupported symbols, but there isn't double spaces or new lines being used for these. Any idea?

Comment: like I said get an extension to highlight problematic characters

Comment: Well depending on what i do I use Webstorm or PHPStorm, but for most things Atom is fine. It has packages for what I described. (I haven't searched for that in JetBrain's products)